# Java Can't insert a UTF-8 cyrillic string into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding

```
Properties properties= new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", login);
properties.setProperty("password", password);
properties.setProperty("useUnicode","true");
properties.setProperty("characterEncoding","UTF-8");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + db, properties);

String message = "Раунд " + nextRoomId;

Data.db.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO chat(message) VALUES('" + message + "')");
```

I get this:

```
Р Р°СѓРЅРґ 338
```

mysql config:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

the tables and database are fully utf-8 encoded, I can't insert a cyrillic string from java, because I get bad encoded string in my table

what I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the editor (IDE) and the javac compiler use the same encoding? The `javac` option is `-encoding UTF-8`. Otherwise there is a wrong conversion for string literals. One can try with `"\u0420\u0430\u0443\u043D\u0434"`. If that works, then there is an issue with the encoding of the .java.

Comment: the editor is using utf-8 without BOM, how do I compile the code with utf-8 encoding?, I've tried this: javac -encoding=UTF-8 Main.java, but the -encoding flag is invalid

Comment: I've tried javac -encoding utf8 Main.java - that worked great, thank you maan!

Comment: Gratulations, UTF-8 I see more and more. Which build system do you use? In _maven_ it is easy: pom.xml, compiler plugin. In _ant_ it is an attribute of the javac task. For the pure taks: `javac -encoding=UTF-8 ...`.

Comment: I just use the standart java compiler and a notepad++ :)

Comment: If you want simpleness you could give the NetBeans IDE a try; yes eclipse is a bit overloaded. BTW I use NotePad++ regularly and favour knowing what happens. But things like autocompletion, javadoc, JSE sources, integration of maven, vcs are unbeatable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to:

```
Properties properties= new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", login);
properties.setProperty("password", password);
properties.setProperty("useUnicode","true");
properties.setProperty("characterEncoding","UTF-8");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + db, properties);

String message = "Раунд " + nextRoomId;
String encMessage = new String(message.getBytes(), "UTF-8");

Data.db.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO chat(message) VALUES('" + encMessage + "')");
```

Comment: tryied that , doesn't helped :(

Comment: if you try to print `message` variable what you get it?

Comment: This worked for me very nice. I had all the encodings of the project, of the MySQL database to utf-8, however still facing the problem for cyrillic characters. With getBytes() the magic happened. Thank you